# Не получается удалить динамически созданный элемент через jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, поиск

Реализую динамический поиск по имени без перезагрузки страницы в Laravel 5.7 c помощью jQuery.
Есть таблица с данными сотрудников и поле поиска.
При поиске данные таблицы очищаются и заполняются данными найденного через поиск сотрудника.
Поиск работает, но при повторном нажатии кнопки, динамически заполненные данные предыдущего поиска не получается удалить и появляются дубликаты данных.
Происходит следующее: 
[image: результаты поиска] 
(должна быть одна запись а не две)

Функция-обработчик поиска, где я пытаюсь реализовать очищение предыдущих данных:

```
  function getMessage() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/search',
        type: "GET",
        dataType : "json",
        data: {
            name: $("#name").val(),
        },
        success: function(result){

                    console.log(result.employee);

            $( "#list" ).empty();//удаляем строки в таблице!
            $( "#list" ).remove();//пробуем так
            $( "#list" ).hide();//и так


            $("#list").html( // вывод результата поиска
                output = "<tr>",
                output += "<th scope='row'>",
                output += "",
                output += "</th>",

                output += "<td>",
                output +="<div class='avatar'>",
                output +="<img  src=\"storage/img/" + result.employee.photo+ "\" alt=\"Аватар\" class=\"avatar__pic\">",
                output +="</div>",
                output += "</td>",

                output += "<td>",
                output += result.employee.name,
                output += "</td>",

                output += "<td>",
                output += result.employee.sociability,
                output += "</td>",

                output += "<td>",
                output += result.employee.engineering,
                output += "</td>",

                output += "<td>",
                output += result.employee.timemanagment,
                output += "</td>",

                output += "<td>",
                output += result.employee.languages,
                output += "</td>",

                output += "<td>",
                output += result.projects.length,
                output += "</td>",

                $( "#table_head" ).append(output)
            );

                 },
        error: function(){alert('No result');}
    });
}
```

Структура формы:

```
<table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-default" id="table_head">
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Фото</th>
            <th>ФИО</th>
            <th >Комуник.</th>
            <th>Инж. навык</th>
            <th>Тайм менедж.</th>
            <th>Знание языков</th>

            <th>Кол. проектов</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>



        <tbody id="list" >
        @foreach($employees as $emp)
            <tr >

                <th scope="row"> {{ ++$i }}</th>

                <td>
                    <div class="avatar">
                        <img  src="{{ Storage::url('img/'.$emp->photo) }} "  alt="Аватар" class="avatar__pic">
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td>{{  $emp->name }}</td>
                <td>{{  $emp->sociability }}</td>
                <td>{{  $emp->engineering }}</td>
                <td>{{  $emp->timemanagment }}</td>
                <td>{{  $emp->languages }}</td>

                <td>{{  count($emp->projects)}}</td>

            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Контроллер:

```
    public function ajaxSearch(Request $search){
//        Получаем значение имени из формы поиска
        $name=$search['name'];

//        Производим поиск  данных в таблице бд по заданому параметру
        $employee = Employee::where('name', $name)->first();

//        Получаем проекты сотрудника
        $projects=$employee->projects;

//        Передаем результат
        return response()->json(['employee'=>$employee, 'projects'=>$projects] );
    }
```

**Обновление**

- забыл закрыть тег tr
- использовал тег th вместо td, для выделения жирным первой ячейки
- идентификатор для вставки строк методом append() выбран неверно
- конструкция $("#list").html(...) была выбрана для изменения содержимого блока #list (почерпнуто из найденных примеров), но в итоге видимо не было потребности в таком нагромождении.

При этих правках все заработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну-с, начнем.

Это что за конструкция? -

```
        $("#list").html( // вывод результата поиска
            output = "<tr>",
            output += "<th scope='row'>",
            output += "",
            output += "</th>",

            ...

            output += "<td>",
            output += result.projects.length,
            output += "</td>",

            $( "#table_head" ).append(output)
        );
```

- почему `<tr>` не закрыт?
- почему в нем `th` вместо `td`?
- почему строки вставляются в заголовок таблицы?
- почему все это находится внутри `$("#list").html(...)`?

---

```
    $("#list").empty();

    var rowHtml = "<tr>";

    rowHtml += "<td>";
    rowHtml += "</td>";

    rowHtml += "<td>";
    rowHtml +="<div class='avatar'>";
    rowHtml +="<img  src=\"storage/img/" + result.employee.photo+ "\" alt=\"Аватар\" class=\"avatar__pic\">";
    rowHtml +="</div>";
    rowHtml += "</td>";

    ...

    rowHtml += "<td>";
    rowHtml += result.projects.length;
    rowHtml += "</td>";

    rowHtml += "</tr>";

    $("#list").append(rowHtml);
```